# Find all matching elements in the array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can someone please help me with this query ??
Query >>> Find  all  warehouses  that keep item "Planner" and having in-stock quantity less than 20

This is the sample document in the items collection of the Inventory database :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6067640da9a907175caaca34"),
    "id" : 101,
    "name" : "Planner",
    "status" : "A",
    "height" : 12,
    "tags" : [
        "mens",
        "womens"
    ],
    "warehouses" : [
        {
            "name" : "Phoenix",
            "quantity" : 25
        },
        {
            "name" : "Quickshift",
            "quantity" : 15
        },
        {
            "name" : "Poona",
            "quantity" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I have tried doing :

```
db.items.find({"name":"Planner","warehouses.quantity":{"$lt":20}},{"warehouses":1,"_id":0}).pretty()
```

But it gives me the result as

```
{
    "warehouses" : [
        {
            "name" : "Phoenix",
            "quantity" : 25
        },
        {
            "name" : "Quickshift",
            "quantity" : 15
        },
        {
            "name" : "Poona",
            "quantity" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/IpD5ypWSZyt

Use aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "name": "Planner" } },
  { $unwind: "$warehouses" }, // break into individual documents
  { $match: { "warehouses.quantity": { $lt: 20 } } }, // query the data
  { $group: { _id: "_id", warehouses: { $push: "$warehouses" } } } // join them back
  ])
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/pdTY0IkIqgF

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) only if you think there will be **only 1 array element matching per document**

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the $elemMatch condition.

```
db.collection.find({
  "name":"Planner",
  "warehouses": { "$elemMatch": { "quantity": { $gt: 20  } } }
},
{ "warehouses.$": 1})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection

Comment: > db.items.find({   "name":"Planner",   "warehouses": { "$elemMatch": { "quantity": { $lt: 20  } } } }, { "warehouses.$": 1}).pretty()
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("6067640da9a907175caaca34"),
 "warehouses" : [
  {
   "name" : "Quickshift",
   "quantity" : 15
  }
 ]
} It should give Ponna warehouse as well as its quantity is less than 20, something is not working

Comment: @AkashTakawale elemMatch operator in find will give only 1 matching result on projection. Use *aggregation* query to get all the results. check this -- https://mongoplayground.net/p/IpD5ypWSZyt